# Spring boot eclipse maven WAS : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory',

Tags: java, jpa, web, spring-boot, websphere

I am trying to deploy my web app to WAS8 but I get this error message. Please help!!

my application work fine when running on command : "mvn spring-boot:run".
I have checked out many website related with how to deploy spring boot project to WAS8, yet I am still failing to make this work.. I do not know what is missing here. I am new to websphere and i do not know much of the configuration for websphere. Please help!!

```
[10/26/16 15:56:24:429 SGT] 000002f9 SystemOut     O 2016-10-26 15:56:24.428  WARN 21564 --- [hreadPool : 707] a.i.JarInputStreamBasedArchiveDescriptor : HHH015010: Unable to find file (ignored): bundleresource://104.fwk1269020858/

java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:75) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:69) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:55) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarInputStreamBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarInputStreamBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) [spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) [spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ...

[10/26/16 15:56:24:847 SGT] 000002f9 SystemOut     O 2016-10-26 15:56:24.846  INFO 21564 --- [hreadPool : 707] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
[10/26/16 15:56:25:192 SGT] 000002f9 SystemOut     O 2016-10-26 15:56:25.192  INFO 21564 --- [hreadPool : 707] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
[10/26/16 15:56:25:232 SGT] 000002f9 SystemOut     O 2016-10-26 15:56:25.232  INFO 21564 --- [hreadPool : 707] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
[10/26/16 15:56:25:528 SGT] 000002f9 SystemOut     O 2016-10-26 15:56:25.528  WARN 21564 --- [hreadPool : 707] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
[10/26/16 15:56:25:546 SGT] 000002f9 SystemOut     O 2016-10-26 15:56:25.546 ERROR 21564 --- [hreadPool : 707] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ...
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.aiahk.FileUpload</groupId>
<artifactId>testUpload</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <!-- for java 6 -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- embedded tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BEGIN downgrade some jar to use java 6 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END downgrade some jar to use java 6 -->


    <!-- for jsp use -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
    <!-- to connect to database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version><!-- for java 6 -->
        <!-- <version>1.3.1</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- for upload file -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To read excel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- to map jodatime in JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- custom jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aiahk.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonUtil</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>web.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>

    <tomcat.version>7.0.52</tomcat.version> 
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my application.properties

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp


# Database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://{xxx}/{yyy}
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update, validate)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect


com.ibm.websphere.persistence.ApplicationsExcludedFromJpaProcessing=*
```

Ps: I do not understand how spring boot project is related to PLAYFRAMEWORK.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20734540/6216002).

Comment: I do not understand the answer, plus I do not use PlayFramework. Is there a step by step to do this right? I have been following many "solutions" online, which I don even understand (of coz i didnt understand. if I do understand, I wouldnt have been asking here).

Comment: Your version of Spring Boot contains Hibernate v4.3.11, which implements JPA 2.1. WAS 8 only supports JPA 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 1.3.5 comes with embedded Hibernate JPA provider (version 4.3, that is already capable to work with JPA 2.1).

Unfortunately, WAS 8.0 supports JPA 2.0 only, so you have to change persistence.xml, so instead

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
 ...
 </persistence>
```

try this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
...
</persistence>
```

Also, if you intend to use Hibernate instead of embedded OpenJPA implementation, you have to turn OpenJPA off by setting JVM property [com.ibm.websphere.persistence.ApplicationsExcludedFromJpaProcessing=*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM26361)

And don't forget to set classloader policy to PARENT_LAST.

The answer is partly covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745542/websphere-8-5-with-jpa-2-1).

Comment: sorry, I do not understand what is PARENT_LAST.
I have changed the persistence.xml and added "com.ibm.websphere.persistence.ApplicationsExcludedFromJpaProcessing=*" in my application.properties. However, the same error is still happening. Why??

Comment: Thanks, Magic Wand, this doesn't solve my problem but thanks for the effort for showing what to do to get it right.