# Weird Hibernate warning in Websphere

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, websphere-8

I've deployed an application that uses hibernate on IBM Websphere 8.5.5.10. 
The hibernate-jpa dependency has provided scope because Websphere has it by default.
The app works but I get the following warning and can't get rid of it.

```
[09.12.16. 14:06:07:231 CET] 000000d8 SystemOut     O 14:06:07.231 WARN  o.h.j.b.a.i.JarInputStreamBasedArchiveDescriptor *- HHH015010: Unable to find file (ignored): bundleresource://130.fwk-1456518464/
java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:87) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarInputStreamBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarInputStreamBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

Can someone help,please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with JPA 2.0 vs 2.1 support. It looks like it has been  covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476026/deploying-application-using-hibernate-jpa-2-1-to-ibm-websphere-gives-nullpointer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257154/spring-boot-eclipse-maven-was-error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfact). Good luck!