# how to prevent WebSphere from auto-creation of EntitMangerFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, websphere

Websphere auto-scan the Persistence.xml file while deploying my application, to create EntitMangerFactory.

My question is how to disable this auto scan to the EntitMangerFactory auto-creation while deploying phase?

websphere 8.5

jpa 22.0

Hibernate 4.2.12

Answer (score 0):

Set JVM property com.ibm.websphere.persistence.ApplicationsExcludedFromJpaProcessing=* to disable Websphere JPA initialization.

As described in the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487223/5116519